# I need to use delegation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everyone I need to use delegation, I'm still new to js, but I hope you can help me. There are 3 blocks, but when you click on 2, 1 opens, you need only 2 to open when you click on 2, and only 1 when you click on 1. Thank you!

```js
let visible = document.querySelector('.card__block');
let unvisible = document.querySelector('.hidden__block');
const card = document.querySelector('.card');

function showHidden() {
  card.onclick = function() {
    card.classList.toggle('open');
    if (card.classList.contains('open')) {
      visible.style.display = 'none'
      unvisible.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      visible.style.display = 'block'
      unvisible.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}

card.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.closest('.card')) {
    showHidden();
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden__block {
  display: none;
}

.card__block {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.hidden__block {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card ">
  <div class="card__block ">
    <div class="card__block-info">
      <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
    <div class="hidden__block-info">
      <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__block ">
    <div class="card__block-info">
      <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
    <div class="hidden__block-info">
      <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__block ">
    <div class="card__block-info">
      <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
    <div class="hidden__block-info">
      <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this happens and only 1 block opens and this is 1

Comment: `querySelector()` only selects the first matching element. Take a look at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) Also, you seem to be editing the `onclick` inside the click event listener, which is very weird?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a full 0 in JS, do I need to change the queryselectorall only for the parent = card? or do the elements too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is delegation

You should not addeventlistener in the click

I wrapped all cards in a container and the blocks in a card div

```js
const cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');

function showHidden(card) {
  const cardBlock = card.querySelector('.card__block');
  const hiddenBlock = card.querySelector('.hidden__block');
  cardBlock.classList.toggle('hidden__block');
  cardBlock.classList.toggle('card__block');
  hiddenBlock.classList.toggle('hidden__block');
  hiddenBlock.classList.toggle('card__block');
}

cardContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const tgt = event.target.closest('.card')
  if (tgt) showHidden(tgt);
});
```

```css
#cardContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden__block {
  display: none;
}

.card__block {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.hidden__block {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__block">
      <div class="card__block-info">
        <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
      <div class="hidden__block-info">
        <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__block">
      <div class="card__block-info">
        <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
      <div class="hidden__block-info">
        <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card__block">
      <div class="card__block-info">
        <h3 class="card__title">Ликвидация пробелов в знаниях учащихся с 5 по 11 класс
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden__block" style="border-radius: 0px 40px;">
      <div class="hidden__block-info">
        <h3 class="hidden__block-title">Подготовка в НИШ, БИЛ для 5 и 6 классов.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, How to make hidden __block appear not on the right but on top of card__block?

Comment: Please see update. I did not quite get your CSS in the beginning